# SQL, sum in column(s) based on date column

Tags: sql, db2

I had a long break from SQL and am a bit rusty. Let's say I have 3 columns in my table: username, value_of_sale, date.

I need a select statement to show me 4 columns based on this table:

```
username
sum of value_of_sales (where date = today)
sum of value_of_sales (where date = today-1)
sum of value_of_sales (where date = today-2)
```

I am using db2.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted any code that you've already worked on and any sample data you have to give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUM` and `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT username,
(CASE WHEN date = CURRENT_DATE THEN value_of_sale ELSE 0 END) AS SUMtoday,
(CASE WHEN date = DAYOFYEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - 1 ) THEN value_of_sale ELSE 0 END) AS SUMtoday-1,
(CASE WHEN date = DAYOFYEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - 2 ) THEN value_of_sale ELSE 0 END) AS SUMtoday-2
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY username
```

Answer (score 1):

Without trying to merge all three of those together, it's very simple to do them individually:

Today:

```
SELECT username, SUM(value_of_sale) FROM `tableName` WHERE DATE(`date`) = CURDATE() GROUP BY username
```

Yesterday:

```
SELECT username, SUM(value_of_sale) FROM `tableName` WHERE DATE(`date`) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) GROUP BY username
```

Two Days Ago:

```
SELECT username, SUM(value_of_sale) FROM `tableName` WHERE DATE(`date`) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 DAY) GROUP BY username
```

`DATE('date')` takes the date portion of the timestamp. If your data is just listed in dates, then you can just compare 'date' to today's date.

`CURDATE()` gets today's date in the server.

`DATE_ADD()` is used to add or subtract days.

Answer (score 1):

```
I have three fields in my table id,sale_amount,created_at(Sales Date)    

SELECT (SELECT sum(sale_amount) FROM `sales` WHERE created_at = 
CURDATE()) AS todaySale,(SELECT sum(sale_amount) FROM `sales` WHERE 
created_at = CURDATE() -1) AS YesterdaySale,(SELECT sum(sale_amount) 
FROM `sales` WHERE created_at = CURDATE() - 2) AS Last2DaysSale
```

This will help you for sure. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most efficient method, but ...

```
select username, 
sum(case when date = today then value_of_sales else 0 end) [Today],
sum(case when date = today-1 then value_of_sales else 0 end) [Yesterday],
sum(case when date = today-2 then value_of_sales else 0 end) [TheDayBefore]
from table
group by username
```